# htaccess - works on local, but not on remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have [this](http://test.gieromaniak.pl) page and *.htaccess* with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/(.*) public_html/images/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^temp/(.*) public_html/temp/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) public_html/css/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) public_html/js/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php/$1 [PT,L,NC,QSA]
```

The thing is, that above *.htaccess* code is working on my local server, but not on remote server.
For example:
this link: http://test.gieromaniak.pl/gallery
should look and work like this: http://test.gieromaniak.pl/public_html/index.php/gallery

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you set `Allow Override` appropriately (e.g. `Allow Override All`) in you httpd.conf?

Comment: @mobius Don't have access to that file on remote server. Must ask my host about that...

Comment: Is the .htaccess doing anything at all? Are you sure it is placed in the correct location?

Comment: Are you certain the host uses Apache?

Comment: @Bas I think, that it's placed in correct location - main directory (public_html).

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, I think, but not sure on 100%

Comment: @Krzysztof I think it needs to be placed in website root folder -- same level as public_html is, and not inside public_html.

Comment: why do you using `PT` flag? And I don't know why you wrote all these rewrites I would go with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: @Vytautas I wrote all these rewrites, because it's framework based site. Pages are linked like `/public_html/index.php/XXX`, and the rest (like JavaScript or CSS) is in `/public_html/css` `/public_html/js` etc. directories. If I would use Your solution, i couldn't use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the public_html folder yourself? If so, that is not your web root and the htaccess should be in the web root, probably one level up from the public_html folder.

Perhaps you copied your entire public_html folder to your webhost, where you should have just uploaded the *contents* of the public_html folder?

Comment: My *public_html* (from *.htaccess* content) is in the root *public_html*. So it's */public_html/public_html*. The *.htaccess* file is in the 1st *public_html* dir.